# Walking a hashmap of hashmaps to retrieve a string value in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm new to Java (and not too comfortable with strong typing) and I have a method that takes in a HashMap. A key in this hashmap contains a key, which has a hashmap for value, which also points to a hashmap, etc, until we reach a string:y

```
HashMap1->HashMap2->HashMap3->HashMap4->String
```

I am trying to access it as follows:

```
HashMap1
    .get("aKey")
    .get("anotherKey")
    .get("yetAnotherKey")
    .get("MyString");
```

But then I get an error,

> Object does not have a method "get(String)

Here is the method, simplified:

```
public HashMap<String, HashMap> getMyString(Map<String, HashMap> hashMap1) {
    String myString = hashMap1
                          .get("aKey")
                          .get("anotherKey")
                          .get("yetAnotherKey")
                          .get("MyString");

    // do something with myString.

    return hashMap1;
}
```

How would someone properly define the method and the parameters to access nested elements easily?

Thank you,

Comment: What is the type parameter of internal `HashMap`? I hope that is **NOT** a map. that's why!

Comment: Maybe your Logic is flawed if you have to use this construct

Comment: are you sure you aren't calling get() on String at last?

Comment: seems you are calling one extra get method. can you add data adding code lines also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that

```
HashMap1.get("aKey") -- > return hashMap2
.get("anotherKey") --> return hashMap3
.get("yetAnotherKey") --> return hashMap4
.get("MyString"); --> return String
```

There is something wrong with the adding part.

Now you have structure like below.

```
hashmap1 --> hashmap2 --> String 

String myString = hashMap1.get("aKey").get("MyString");
```

That is how it should be.

Comment: The structure was imposed by JSON being parsed and converted to a LinkedHashMap. However, I extracted the values earlier on and didn't have to run with this issue in my method.

Answer (score 1):

You made too many `.get` calls. Probably the last one is not needed.

Can you just create `class CompoundKey` with arbitrary number of String fields and use it as a key? It would simplify your design.

To use it properly in Java you need to override `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

Comment: Accorrding to him its like that. 

HashMap1.get("aKey") -- > return hashMap2
.get("anotherKey") --> return hashMap 3
.get("yetAnotherKey") --> return hashMap4
.get("MyString"); --> return String

seems nothing wrong with retrieving part. right?

Answer (score 0):

You should first of all use interfaces not implementation, therefore use `Map` (and not HashMap) where possible.

And second, you should repair your Generics and use all levels. Now the compiler can help you and possible show your error.

```
// i suppose you want to return a String, at least the method name tells it
public String getMyString(Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> hashMap1) {
    String myString = hashMap1
                      .get("aKey")
                      .get("anotherKey")
                      .get("yetAnotherKey")
                      .get("MyString");

    return myString;
}
```

Yet i suggest that you use a different data structure.